# Reg Expression characters to numbers

Tags: regex

I want to ask about regExp, I need regExp, which work like this:

input = '569/A';
result = '569-1';

input = '569/a';
result = '569-2';

input = '569/B';
result = '569-3';

input = '569/b';
result = '569-4';

You definitely  understand the pattern which I want. '/' or '\' converted in '-', Characters should be converted in numeric with proper sequence A = 1, a = 2, B=3, b=4. Uppercase on odd numeric and Lowercase on even numeric

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Regexes cannot do this since they can only work with existing text, not generate new text.

Comment: I was mean that search in replace string just like php preg_rplace but for it i need pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use .replace() - it will be much easier.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

.replace('/','-').replace('A','1').replace('a','2').replace('B','3').replace('b','4');

Comment: For the love of Berners-Lee, please don't mention w3fools.com here!